# Need urgent help - car cut out and instruments frozen and will not start

Tags: electronic-control-module, fuse, instrument, instrument-cluster, breakdown

I have just broken down. I am safe. My car has suddenly cut out and my instruments are frozen. The car will turn over but it refuses to start. My fuel gauge is stuck as well. My engine is cold so I do not know about the temperature gauge

[image]

This is with the key removed from the car.

When I turn to run, with the warning light test I get NO emissions lamp or engine warning light. My odometer does not work either. I get a blank screen. I get the EPS lamp, the airbag light, the oil and battery lamp (when the keys are in the engine run position). The airbag lamp goes out after a while as in this photo.

[image]

My car is a 2003 Opel Agila 1.2

Please help. I do not have breakdown cover and I am miles from home.

My clock and temperature display in the centre console does not turn on at all either and neither does the radio. It appears that no power is getting to them. My battery is fine I think as the car turns over. This happens no matter if the key is in or out of the ignition or what position the key is in the ignition

Comment: Sorry, I can't rotate images on my phone.

Comment: Can you check the fuse? The ECU fuse older cars have a single fuse for many things clubbed together

Comment: @Anarach I checked all the main fuses in the engine compartment and they all looked fine.

Comment: I have now abandoned the car so I cannot do any more checks until tomorrow :(

Comment: Man....that is brutal.  I'm thinking BCM?  It's as if your ignition switch is bad too?????   Sorry to hear about this @George .  Hope this is a cheap fix!

Comment: You might want to try and disconnect your battery to reset your BCM.....????

Comment: I've got a taxi and a train home. I had to abandon my car as I do not have breakdown cover *facepalm*. Anyway, I pulled out all the big fuses in the engine compartment and the hazards stopped flashing. I tried to jump start but it still would not fire, as the battery went flat and wouldn't turn over at all (in just under 2 hours). The only load I had was the hazards.

Comment: Check your insurance - you may have breakdown cover in there also.

Comment: This is a Daewoo "Cruise" platform vehicle, no?  I'm not a GM guy, but what very little I know is when I see cluster needles frozen midrange, time to scope out the Body Control Module as DucatiKiller suggested.  I don't know what an Agilia is, but sounds just about right for the Lutz approved Korean platform, used worldwide Opel/GM/Chevy/etc.  Check the BCM.  And by the way, if BCM ain't happy, you don't start.  Ever.  A jealous genius wife is easier to fool than a General Motors Body Control Module,

Comment: I have purchased breakdown cover and will update on Sunday which is the first point at which I can get recovery

Comment: @George  Did you ever figure out what happened?

Comment: Yes, I have written an answer over what happened. Why have I been downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. I purchased breakdown cover and called the AA out on Sunday afternoon. They were very fast and the guy was incredibly helpful. He said that a fuse had blown, and checked the fuses. He then found a blown fuse and replaced it for another one, but as soon as it touched it instantly blew again.

So he looked up on his computer to see which circuits run off of that fuse, and it was the clock, radio and instruments. He disconnected the battery for 5 mins and then put another fuse in, and the instruments reset and the car started

I drove about 100m down the road and the exact same thing happened. The AA guy checked his computer, and the radio and clock ran off of this, so he removed the radio wiring adaptor and the clock as well, and the car started and ran. I have had no more problems with it, and I have reinstalled things one by one to see what the problem was.

The clock is fine, but the radio/stereo is completely dead. I plugged it in and had sparks flying everywhere, so I am going to replace the radio.

My advice to anyone suffering this problem is to check all of their fuses first before doing anything, as this could be a simple fix for a massive failure.